# Dynamic merging of cells in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, merge, conditional-statements, dynamic, cells

In an SSRS Report ,I have a table which has 14 columns, 1st column is 7am and the last column is 7pm.
I have 100 records with conference names and the timings,

ex:

1. international conference 9am to 5pm
2. national conference 8 am to 11 am

so the problem is these column cells must merge based on the timings and display as one textbox with center aligning the text

ex: national conference the columns from 8 to 11 am are to be merged and the time 8 to 11am must display in these merged cells with center align.

Can anyone give me any suggestion for this issue, i thought to write custom code for this but i did not get any idea.

So, If anyone can help me i will be very grateful.

(Can we merge the cells dynamically based on the condition in SSRS)

Answer (score 2):

I would duplicate this row so there will be one row with merged cells, second with separate.
Then Hidden propperty of 1st row should be set to

```
 = (Fields!ConferenceName = "interenational")
```

And for the 2nd row

```
 = (Fields!ConferenceName = "national")
```