# ReportViewer Merge cells dynamically on condition

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

I was wondering if we could merge cells dynamically on condition. Like I have 2 columns Description1 and Description2 and want to merge if Description2 is empty.

One more thing, How can I Page Break after certain rows like 100 rows than page break?

Any please

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is possible.

One work-around is to duplicate the row and only merge cells in the second one, then toggle the row visibility instead, as suggested here:
[Dynamic merging of cells in SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611962/dynamic-merging-of-cells-in-ssrs)

Another way to do it, since you're hosting the report in an HTML page, could be to add some JavaScript on the page to post-process the table. You can also do it on the server side by inheriting the ReportViewer and overriding OnRender.